# Select all columns but distinct from database table in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

Bellow SQL command runs perfectly :

```
select * from `product` group by `owner_name` order by `id` asc
```

When I translate above code in my Laravel project to get the same result :

```
Product::select('*')
        ->orderBy('id','asc')->groupBy('owner_name')
         ->get();
```

This laravel code returns me error that

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055
>   'db1.product.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `product` group
>   by `owner_name` order by `id` asc)

Problem is I have many duplicated records with slight differences on some of their columns. I need to get them by owner_name and only one time .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your applications's database config file `config/database.php`

In mysql array, set `strict => false` to disable MySQL's strict mode

Comment: Wow , that easy !  ,  I was playing with this block of code for a day and I thought there is something wrong with my Mysql code  . Thanks.

Comment: @MacTaylor please accept answer if its helpful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have don't need to do 'select(*)', by default it will select all columns data.

Try this:

```
Product::orderBy('id','asc')->groupBy('owner_name')
     ->get();
```

And if you want to fetch selected column you can do like this:

```
Product::select(['column_1', 'column_2'])
    ->orderBy('id','asc')->groupBy('owner_name')
     ->get();
```